# Axon 4.3 - consume message from topic kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, event-handling, spring-kafka, axon

I'm using Axon version (4.3) which seamlessly supports Kafka with annotation in the SpringBoot Main class using

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)
```

In my case the message is sotred in the topic successfully, but the problem with this consumer, i can't consume the message from the topic.

y a-t-il une configuration manquante?

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>4.3</version>
   <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>axon-server-connector</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.axonframework.extensions.kafka</groupId>
   <artifactId>axon-kafka-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>4.0-RC3</version>
 </dependency>
```

**application.yml**

```
axon:
  eventhandling:
    processors:
      conventions:
        source: kafkaMessageSource
        mode: tracking
  serializer:
    general: jackson
  kafka:
    client-id: consumer_service
    default-topic: topic_x
    bootstrap-servers:
    - 127.0.0.1:9092
```

**Listener.java**

```
//@Component
@ProcessingGroup(value = "conventions")
public class Listener {

 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenericListener.class);

 @EventHandler
 void on(ConventionCreatedEvent event) {
  LOGGER.info("got the event {}", event);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the name of the *Kafka message source* within your configuration which is the culprit right now Aymen.

When using Axon's auto configuration and the Axon-Kafka auto configuration without any specifics on which type of Kafka message source you desire, a `StreamableKafkaMessageSource` will be created. The name of that bean will be the `streamableKafkaMessageSource`.

In your `application.yml` you however expect the `source` for your `conventions` Tracking Event Processor to be called `kafkaMessageSource`.

Next to this you can have a look at the [example application](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kafka/tree/master/kafka-axon-example) contained within Axon's Kafka Extension. Maybe that makes things a bit more clear.

Comment: thnx Steven for your answer. I tried to change `kafkaMessageSource` to `streamableKafkaMessageSource`, but it stayed the same problem.
I pushed my project in github: https://github.com/akanzari/axon-kafka

Comment: To be completely honest with you, I would try to use code-based configuration for this component. Although in essence it should work, as the Axon Kafka Spring Boot auto configurer creates a `StreamableKafkaMessageSource` bean called `streamableKafkaMessageSource`, I cannot say I have tested that out myself. Although I guess you prefer property file configs from the looks of your project, that is not what the sample I have shared does either.

Comment: Would you be up for giving that a go to see if it works?  Normally I would give your sample project a run, but I will be off for the upcoming three weeks with still plenty of other work to go around.